# Can't prove seemingly trivial equality in Ada Spark

Tags: ada

So I have those two files.

testing.ads

```
package Testing with
   SPARK_Mode
is

   function InefficientEuler1Sum2 (N: Natural) return Natural;

   procedure LemmaForTesting with
     Ghost,
     Post => (InefficientEuler1Sum2(0) = 0);

end Testing;
```

and testing.adb

```
package body Testing with
   SPARK_Mode
is

   function InefficientEuler1Sum2 (N: Natural) return Natural is
      Sum: Natural := 0;
   begin
      for I in 0..N loop
         if I mod 3 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 5 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 15 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum - I;
         end if;
      end loop;
      return Sum;
   end InefficientEuler1Sum2;

   procedure LemmaForTesting
   is
   begin
      null;
   end LemmaForTesting;

end Testing;
```

When I run SPARK -> Prove File, I get such message:

```
GNATprove
    E:\Ada\Testing SPARK\search\src\testing.ads
        10:14 medium: postcondition might fail
           cannot prove InefficientEuler1Sum2(0) = 0
```

Why is that so? What I have misunderstood or maybe done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prove the trivial equality, you need to make sure it is covered by the function's post-condition. If so, you can prove the equality using a simple `Assert` statement as shown in the example below. No lemma is needed at this point.

However, a post-condition is not enough to prove the absence of runtime errors (AoRTE): given the allowable input range of the function, the summation may, for some values of `N`, overflow. To mitigate the issue, you need to bound the input values of `N` and show the prover that the value for `Sum` remains bounded during the loop using a loop invariant (see [here](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-spark/chapters/05_Proof_Of_Functional_Correctness.html#handling-of-loops), [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/spark2014/html/spark2014_ug/en/source/how_to_write_loop_invariants.html) and [here](https://blog.adacore.com/gnatprove-tips-and-tricks-how-to-write-loop-invariants) for some background information on loop invariants). For illustration purposes, I've chosen a conservative bound of `(2 * I) * I`, which will severely restrict the allowable range of input values, but does allow the prover to proof the absence of runtime errors in the example.

**testing.ads**

```
package Testing with SPARK_Mode is

   --  Using the loop variant in the function body, one can guarantee that no
   --  overflow will occur for all values of N in the range 
   --
   --     0 .. Sqrt (Natural'Last / 2)   <=>   0 .. 32767
   --
   --  Of course, this bound is quite conservative, but it may be enough for a
   --  given application.
   --
   --  The post-condition can be used to prove the trivial equality as stated
   --  in your question.
   
   subtype Domain is Natural range 0 .. 32767;
   
   function Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 (N : Domain) return Natural
     with Post => (if N = 0 then Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2'Result = 0);

end Testing;
```

**testing.adb**

```
package body Testing with SPARK_Mode  is

   -------------------------------
   -- Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 --
   -------------------------------
   
   function Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 (N : Domain) return Natural is
      Sum: Natural := 0;
   begin
      
      for I in 0 .. N loop
         
         if I mod 3 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 5 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 15 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum - I;
         end if;
         
         --  Changed slightly since initial post, no effect on Domain.
         pragma Loop_Invariant (Sum <= (2 * I) * I);
         
      end loop;
      
      return Sum;
      
   end Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2;

end Testing;
```

**main.adb**

```
with Testing; use Testing;

procedure Main with SPARK_Mode is
begin
   pragma Assert (Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 (0) = 0);   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ gnatprove -Pdefault.gpr -j0 --level=1 --report=all
Phase 1 of 2: generation of Global contracts ...
Phase 2 of 2: flow analysis and proof ...
main.adb:5:19: info: assertion proved
testing.adb:13:15: info: division check proved
testing.adb:14:24: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:16:15: info: division check proved
testing.adb:17:24: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:19:15: info: division check proved
testing.adb:20:24: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:20:24: info: range check proved
testing.adb:23:33: info: loop invariant preservation proved
testing.adb:23:33: info: loop invariant initialization proved
testing.adb:23:42: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:23:46: info: overflow check proved
testing.ads:17:19: info: postcondition proved
Summary logged in /obj/gnatprove/gnatprove.out
```