# How to prove equivalence of two functions?

Tags: ada, spark-ada

I have two functions: InefficientEuler1Sum and InefficientEuler1Sum2. I want to prove that they both are equivalent (same output given same input).
When I run SPARK -> Prove File (in GNAT Studio), I get such messages about line `pragma Loop_Invariant(Sum = InefficientEuler1Sum(I));` in the file euler1.adb:

1. `loop invariant might fail in first iteration`
2. `loop invariant might not be preserved by an arbitrary iteration`

It seems (for example, when trying manual proof) that function InefficientEuler1Sum2 has no idea about structure of InefficientEuler1Sum. What's the best way to give this information to it?

File euler1.ads:

```
package Euler1 with
   SPARK_Mode
is

   function InefficientEuler1Sum (N: Natural) return Natural with
     Ghost,
     Pre => (N <= 1000);

   function InefficientEuler1Sum2 (N: Natural) return Natural with
     Ghost,
     Pre => (N <= 1000),
     Post => (InefficientEuler1Sum2'Result = InefficientEuler1Sum (N));

end Euler1;
```

File euler1.adb:

```
package body Euler1 with
   SPARK_Mode
is

   function InefficientEuler1Sum(N: Natural) return Natural is
      Sum: Natural := 0;
   begin
      for I in 0..N loop
         if I mod 3 = 0 or I mod 5 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         pragma Loop_Invariant(Sum <= I * (I + 1) / 2);
      end loop;
      return Sum;
   end InefficientEuler1Sum;

   function InefficientEuler1Sum2 (N: Natural) return Natural is
      Sum: Natural := 0;
   begin
      for I in 0..N loop
         if I mod 3 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 5 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum + I;
         end if;
         if I mod 15 = 0 then
            Sum := Sum - I;
         end if;
         pragma Loop_Invariant(Sum <= 2 * I * I);
         pragma Loop_Invariant(Sum = InefficientEuler1Sum(I));
      end loop;
      return Sum;
   end InefficientEuler1Sum2;

end Euler1;
```

Comment: It appears that your post conditions for both functions are insufficient. There is no post condition for InefficientEuler1Sum and the existing post condition for InefficientEuler1Sum2 does not relate its input to its output. The two functions can only be proven to have equal outputs if the outputs are specified.

Comment: What kind of postcondition do you suggest to write for InefficientEuler1Sum? (Let's suppose for a moment that I don't know the closed form expression for it.) Also disagree about the post condition of InefficientEuler1Sum2, because there's clearly InefficientEuler1Sum2'Result here... Anyway, I could be wrong... Can you, if possible, show how you would prove the equivalence?

Comment: Given the loop invariants in both functions it is clear that the two functions will often produce different results. Sum <= I * (I + 1) / 2 is clearly not the same range of values as Sum <= 2 * I * I for the same input value N. For instance, if N = 3 then the final value for the loop invariant in one function is 6 while the final value for the loop invariant in the other is 18.

Comment: @JimRogers This is not correct. It's *not* clear "that the two functions will often produce different results". The loop invariants assert that the value of `Sum` remains below (or at) a certain bound in both functions. They don't assert a concrete value of `Sum` and do not prove anything regarding function's concrete result for a given input `N` other than a range. The OP just used a different (less conservative) bound in `InefficientEuler1Sum` (based on arithmetic progression, very nice actually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proving that the two functions are equivalent using an assertion like:

```
pragma Assert
  (for all I in 0 .. 1000 =>
     Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum (I) = Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 (I));
```

seems kind of hard. Such an assertion requires post-conditions on both functions that would convince the prover that such a condition holds. I don't know how to do this at this point (others may know though).

***Side-note**: The main difficulty I see here is how to formulate a post-condition (on either function) that both describes the relation between the function's input and the output, and, at the same time, can be proven using suitable loop invariants. Formulating these suitable loop invariants seems challenging as the update pattern of the `Sum` variable is periodic over multiple iterations (for `InefficientEuler1Sum` the period is 5, for `InefficientEuler1Sum2` it's 15). I'm not sure (at this point) how to formulate a loop invariant that can deal with this kind of behavior.*

Hence, another (though less exciting approach) would be to show the equivalence of both *methods* by putting them in a common loop and then asserting the equivalence of each of the method's accumulation (`Sum`) variable in a loop invariant and final assertion (as shown below). One of the variables is marked as a ["ghost" variable](https://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/ug/en/source/specification_features.html#ghost-code) as it's pointless to actually compute the sum twice: you need a second `Sum` variable only for the proof.

For the example below: package spec. and a main file as in the other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64659195/10975520).

**testing.adb**

```
package body Testing with SPARK_Mode is
   
   -------------------------------
   -- Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 --
   -------------------------------
   
   function Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2 (N : Domain) return Natural is      
      Sum_1 : Natural := 0;
      Sum_2 : Natural := 0 with Ghost;
   begin
      
      for I in 0 .. N loop

         --  Method 1
         begin
            if I mod 3 = 0 then
               Sum_1 := Sum_1 + I;
            end if;
            if I mod 5 = 0 then
               Sum_1 := Sum_1 + I;
            end if;
            if I mod 15 = 0 then
               Sum_1 := Sum_1 - I;
            end if;
         end;
         
         --  Method2
         begin
            if I mod 3 = 0 or I mod 5 = 0 then
               Sum_2 := Sum_2 + I;
            end if;
         end; 
         
         pragma Loop_Invariant (Sum_1 <= (2 * I) * I);
         pragma Loop_Invariant (Sum_2 <= I * (I + 1) / 2);
         pragma Loop_Invariant (Sum_1 = Sum_2); 
         
      end loop;
            
      pragma Assert (Sum_1 = Sum_2);      
      return Sum_1;
      
   end Inefficient_Euler_1_Sum_2;

end Testing;
```

**output**

```
$ gnatprove -Pdefault.gpr -j0 --level=1 --report=all
Phase 1 of 2: generation of Global contracts ...
Phase 2 of 2: flow analysis and proof ...
main.adb:5:19: info: assertion proved
testing.adb:18:18: info: division check proved
testing.adb:19:31: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:21:18: info: division check proved
testing.adb:22:31: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:24:18: info: division check proved
testing.adb:25:31: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:25:31: info: range check proved
testing.adb:31:18: info: division check proved
testing.adb:31:33: info: division check proved
testing.adb:32:31: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:36:33: info: loop invariant initialization proved
testing.adb:36:33: info: loop invariant preservation proved
testing.adb:36:45: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:36:50: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:37:33: info: loop invariant initialization proved
testing.adb:37:33: info: loop invariant preservation proved
testing.adb:37:44: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:37:49: info: overflow check proved
testing.adb:37:54: info: division check proved
testing.adb:38:33: info: loop invariant initialization proved
testing.adb:38:33: info: loop invariant preservation proved
testing.adb:42:22: info: assertion proved
testing.ads:18:19: info: postcondition proved
Summary logged in /obj/gnatprove/gnatprove.out
```